# difference between authentication and permission in Django rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What is the difference between authentication and permission in Django Rest-framework? How do this two classes cooperate each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Permission](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)**

> Object level permissions are used to determine if a user should be
>   allowed to act on a particular object, which will typically be a model
>   instance.

**[Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)**

> Authentication is the mechanism of associating an incoming request
>   with a set of identifying credentials, such as the user the request
>   came from, or the token that it was signed with. The permission and
>   throttling policies can then use those credentials to determine if the
>   request should be permitted.

A quote by Apple developer goes as,

> Authentication or identification by itself is not usually
>   sufficient to gain access to information or code. For that, the entity
>   requesting access must have authorization.

To keep things simple,

> Permission checks will typically
>   use the authentication information in the request.user and
>   request.auth properties to determine if the incoming request should be
>   permitted.
>
> Permissions are used to grant or deny access different classes of
>   users to different parts of the API.

To know more on how they interact, take a look at [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#how-permissions-are-determined)

Hope it helps!